# Android - audio recording in HTC phones

Tags: java, android

When I'm use Samsung or any other Android phones I have no problem, but when i want to use my HTC One X+ the recorder crashes and wouldn't start.

Here is the logcat output:

```
    ⁃   11-18 18:37:39.963: E/MediaRecorder(27698): start failed: -2147483648
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.963: E/MediaRecorder(27698): start failed.
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.963: E/MediaRecorder(27698): try to delete broken file: /storage/emulated/0/callrec/+989203626397_10|18|-18:37.AAC
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.968: W/dalvikvm(27698): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f86a08)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:805)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at com.hudg.callrec.Main$PhoneCallListener.StartRecording(Main.java:256)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at com.hudg.callrec.Main$PhoneCallListener.onCallStateChanged(Main.java:215)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:739)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
⁃   11-18 18:37:39.973: E/AndroidRuntime(27698):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is my code ! :

```
public void StartRecording(){
        MediaRecorder recorder;
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        recorder.setOutputFile(Environments.getExternalStorageDirectory+"test"+".AAC");
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("MSG", "Could not Prepare Recorder !");
        }
        recorder.start();
        Log.d("MSG", "Recording finaly started !!!!!");
    }
```

this is the new Logcat errors ! :
[image]

Comment: You should probably post the code where you set up the `MediaRecorder` instance.

Comment: @Michael finally added !

Comment: please help me ! I'm gonna crazy !

Comment: Well, `start()` can throw execptions, so the call to `start()` ought to be in a `try { } catch () { }` block. The error code in the log seems to be `UNKNOWN_ERROR`, so it's not really possible to determine why it failed just from those logs.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ?

Comment: @JCasso I'm already using this permission !

Comment: @Michael i tried ` try{ } catch(){ } ` but nothing changed and it says : start called in invalid state : 4

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set other audio encoder or output format?

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Output file name could be set by other way, as mentioned JCasso:

```
file = FileUtil.getRecordingFile("aac").getAbsolutePath();
recorder.setOutputFile(file);

recorder.prepare();
```

Comment: im also tried to rename file correctly and also phone is not mounted to PC ! but problem continues @TgVikor (I'm updated post #1 with new picture that contains new error message !)

Answer (score 0):

```
recorder.setOutputFile(Environments.getExternalStorageDirectory+"test"+".AAC");
```

Something is wrong with your output file name. You do not name it "test.AAC" according to the error log.

> +989203626397_10|18|-18:37.AAC

is **not** a valid file name.

Edit:
Also make sure that sdcard is not mounted to pc.

Comment: im also tried to rename file correctly and also phone is not mounted to PC ! but problem continues @JCasso (I'm updated post #1 with new picture that contains new error message !)

Comment: The logs in the image you posted indicate that you haven't fixed the filename. And they don't match the code you've posted.

Comment: @Michael i don't edit the code but in my app i save file with name correctly : incoming number + date + time . but there is no changes all things is right when I'm use my Note 2 is ok but in One X+ it crashes!

Comment: It's entirely possible that the filesystem used for the SD card on the phone where this fails doesn't allow some of the characters you use in your filenames (for example `'|'`). Try using a filename with only alphanumeric characters and underscores.

Comment: @Michael I'm tired with this file name 'incoming number.AAC' but nothing changed ! when i use samsung android phone its ok but in HTC one plus and HTC one sv and other HTC devices it has log cat problem!

Comment: Does "incoming_number" contain any non-alphanumeric characters (like a leading '+')? Try something like "test.aac" instead.

Comment: @Michael incoming_number is : 123456789 ! and does not contains any special characteres and also + !